# vue js cannot read property of undefined

Tags: loops, vue.js, properties, undefined, v-for

I use a `v-for` loop to list buttons for each category in my array. A function is called on click but it returns an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Every button is properly displayed in HTML with its name.

**v-for loop:**

```html
<button :class="{selected: category.exist === true}" v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" v-on:click="pushFilter(); category.exist = !category.exist">{{ category.name }} {{ category.exist }}</button>
```

**categories data:**

```js
export default {
  data: function () {   
    return {
      categories: [
        {
          name: 'name1',
          exist: false,
        },
        {
          name: 'name2',
          exist: false,
        },
      ],
```

**Method:**

```js
methods: {
  pushFilter() {
    console.log(this.category.name);
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pushFilter()` references `this.category`, but the component has no `category` prop (at least none shown in question). You're probably trying to access the `category` iterator of `v-for`. You could just pass that in the template binding:

```html
<button v-for="category in categories" v-on:click="pushFilter(category)">
```

And update your method to receive the `category` argument:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    pushFilter(category) {
      console.log(category.name)
    }
  }
}
```